# Probability distribution with maximal entropy on $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For given closed set $F$ on $\mathbb R$ one can think of probability distribution $\mathbb P^\ast_F$ with support on $F$ and with maximal entropy. It is well known that

- If $F=[0,1]$ then $\mathbb P^\ast_F = \mathsf U[0,1]$,
- If $F=\mathbb R$ then $\mathbb P^\ast_F = \mathsf N(0,1)$ (if we make additional assumption of zero mean and unit variance for considered distributions),
- If $F = [0,+\infty)$ then $\mathbb P^\ast_F = \mathsf {Exp}(1)$ (again under assumptions of mean and variance to be fixed),
- If $F = \{0\} \cup \{1\} \cup \ldots \cup \{n\}$ then $\mathbb P^\ast_F = \mathsf U(F)$.

But what is the distribution with maximal entropy with support on $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$? It can't be $\mathsf U[0,1]$ because its support will be $[0,1]$. Then I think that it may be a mixture of $\mathsf U[0,1]$ and of distribution concentrated in $\{2\}$ with coefficients $\frac 1 2$. But what is the way to proove this directly?

Additional question: is it true that maximal entropy is always attained on some distribution if we consider compact $F$? It it also true that maximal entropy is always attained on some distribution if we consider an arbitrary closed $F$ and distributions with fixed mean and variance?

Comment: There may be something missing in the problem description. As it stands, your examples are wrong. There are no distributions with maximal entropy on $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$, since you can always spread the distribution out further.

Comment: @joriki for $\mathbb R$ and $[0,+\infty)$ we consider only distributions with fixed mean and variance, right? But I think that for the case of support $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ we don't need to make such assumption

Comment: How do you mean, "right?" :-) You're asking the question, it's your call which distributions you want to consider. But if you do only want to consider distributions with fixed mean and variance, you should say so in the question.

Comment: @joriki I mean by "right" that I forgot about this when I was asking a question. So now I remember that for noncompact supports we have to require additionaly the fixed variance and mean to have a distribution on which the maximal entropy is attained (but I'm not sure that it is sufficient for any unbounded closed set that we consider as support). But If I'm not mistaken the distribution with maximal entropy on compacts exists (I may be mistaken).

Comment: How do you define entropy for a mixed discrete and continuous distribution?

Comment: @joriki I was thinking that natural way is to represent $\mathbb P^\ast_F$ as a sum of descrete and continuous measures. But now I'm not sure that this definition will be correct. Do you know a way how to do it?

Comment: Or we can approximate our distribution by continuous and take limit (also not sure)